# Closing a project in Android Studio 4.0 does not open the Android Studio recent project list window

Tags: android, android-studio-4.0

When I close a project in android studio by going to file -> close project, sometimes it just unloads all open documents and stays in this window:

[image]

It is supposed to go this window, that contains a list of recently opened Android Studio projects

[image]

How do I force it to open this window when I close a project? I am using Android Studio 4.0.

EDIT: solve using this method: [How to force Android Studio to start with the welcome screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181847/how-to-force-android-studio-to-start-with-the-welcome-screen)

Comment: looks like a bug in AS4.0. But why do you need the welcome screen, does the menu at the top not work?

Comment: @Henry Opening a project from File -> open sometimes just stays in the same screen as the first picture. I'm also just more used to the welcome screen. Is there a way to force it to display welcome screen, like some keyboard shortcut or a toolbar button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After updating Android Studio from 3.6 to 4.0, close project not works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274740/after-updating-android-studio-from-3-6-to-4-0-close-project-not-works)

Comment: Please try this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63026629/7200133

Comment: @GkMohammadEmon no it doesn't

Comment: Noticing the same thing after latest android studio update